# Shouldn't an accepted answer count towards the Teacher badge?

Tags: feature-request

I found a user on Stack Overflow yesterday that had three answers in their profile.  All three had zero votes, but one was an accepted answer (not from their own question).

If someone accepts your answer, doesn't that imply you are a teacher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Teacher badge, it says

> Answered first question with score of 1 or more.

Having a score of "1 or more" is a validation from the community that the answer was voted by the majority as "useful." That's to avoid awarding the badge for trivial or wrong answers.

The accepted answer function doesn't have that check. It is only the opinion of one person. If the answer was down-voted by the community at large, the original author should not be able to overrule simply by accepting the answer (awarding the Teacher badge).

Up-voting and accepting an answer are serve two different purposes. Ideally, if the author saw fit to accept the answer, they should have up-voted. But ultimately voting a question as "useful" is a function of the *community* vote.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.